# Row appends to existing data in wrong column

Tags: curl, google-sheets-api

I have only one row `1,[space],3` which I input it manually:

[image]

Then I want to append a new row with 3 cells `1,2,3` using the Sheets REST API

```js
curl -X POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/12_Ci93pDWrmQGLt3D5jg_Vb7Xi7vmHI9o62F58dpLeA/values/aaa%21A1%3AC1:append?insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&valueInputOption=RAW' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer ya29.GlvgBH1pkFnZKs8cz0s0o7VyPUloPma1i2ZU-JUJGczIfFGy1Iw2XJUOMh4L9r2pTNYYVsmhMdf-2LfW4J38RMe5FosfeQjcTsZ6SiIGq1wcDzvSQjeHdY0P7iDh' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'postman-token: b6de9e14-d792-98a5-6d6d-183a1034cea5' \
  -d '{ "majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [ [ "1", "2", "3" ] ] } '
```

It's strange that the newly added row has two spaces at the head `[space],[space],1,2,3`, if the first row has no space, it would be normal as `1,2,3`

[image]

Please advise: how can I add it without these 2 spaces?

Comment: Add `json` `Google-sheets-api` and `curl` tag

Comment: It seems that I change the range from A1:C1 to A1 would resolve the issue.

Comment: I think this is still an issue although my problem is fixed :)

Comment: Review the docs on appending values: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one row, and you want to append a new row (1,2,3).
The range either should be A2:C2 or A1.

I put A1:C1, it causes incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a blank column (like you have in column B), it will cause an issue. When appending, be sure to have the previous row filled with non-blank data.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this same issue by providing only A1 as the range. This allows the Google Sheets API to always pick the correct "Virtual" table to append to. I was previously providing A:I, and the blank fields cause weird behaviors when appending.

This article is what helped me:
https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/537#issuecomment-586622830

```
var valueRange = new ValueRange();
valueRange.MajorDimension = "ROWS";
valueRange.Values = request.Models.Select(x =>
{
    return new List<object> {
        x.Field1,
        x.FieldThatWasBlank,
        x.Field2,
        x.Field3
    };
}).ToList<IList<object>>();

var requestAppend = clientSheets.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, request.Id, $"{_SHEET_NAME}!A1");
requestAppend.ValueInputOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.ValueInputOptionEnum.USERENTERED;
var respAppend = await requestAppend.ExecuteAsync();
```